# Observable not changing for virtual data in Kendo Combobox

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-3.0

I have some strange problem. I have Kendo + Knockout on my page. Because of many items, I tried to setup virtualization on Kendo ComboBox. But for some reason first change of combobox doesn't fire onChange event and observable is not changed. Why?

If I understand, only function of value mapper is to provide index of item in data collection. So it should be ok.

Another problem should be in autoBind property on combobox. If set to false, it seems to be working, but initial value is not bound in combo. How to solve this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RaptorCZ/442h4djr/

```
var dataToDisplay = [
    {
        "BrokerID": 1,
        "DisplayName": "Broker ID 1"
    },
    {
        "BrokerID": 2,
        "DisplayName": "Broker ID 2"
    },
    {
        "BrokerID": 3,
        "DisplayName": "Broker ID 3"
    },
    {
        "BrokerID": 4,
        "DisplayName": "Broker ID 4"
    },
    {
        "BrokerID": 5,
        "DisplayName": "Broker ID 5"
    }
]

/** VM */
var ViewModel = function () {

    // Observable with initial value
    this.selectedID = ko.observable(2);

    /** Kendo Grid Definition */
    GetKendoComboBoxForRoleDefinition = function (context)
        {
            var self = this;
            return {
                autoBind: true,
                valuePrimitive: true,
                value: context.selectedID,
                dataTextField: 'DisplayName',
                dataValueField: 'BrokerID',
                filter: 'contains',
                virtual:
                {
                    //itemHeight: 26,
                    valueMapper: function (options)
                    {
                        var index = -1;

                        /** Find selected item in data collection */
                        var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(dataToDisplay, function (item)
                        {
                            toastr.info(item.BrokerID + ' - ' + options.value);
                            return item.BrokerID == options.value;
                        });

                        if (item)
                        {
                            /** Get index of selected item */
                            index = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(dataToDisplay, item);
                        }

                        toastr.info('valueMapper -> ' + options.value + ', Index: ' + index);

                        options.success([index]);
                    }
                },
                //height: 520,
                //data: undefined,
                dataSource:
                {
                    type: 'json',
                    transport:
                    {
                        read: function (options)
                        {
                            toastr.info('Transport.read()... ' + dataToDisplay.length + ' item(-s)');
                            options.success(dataToDisplay);
                        }
                    },
                    //pageSize: 80,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true
                },
                change: function (e)
                {
                    toastr.info('Combo changed to index ' + this.selectedIndex);
                }
            }
        }

};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` parameter of the ComboBox takes a string, not a number. The options are converted to strings, but the initial value you assign the observable is not. So the first change makes it a string value, and it's happy after that.

You just need

```
var dataToDisplay = [
    {
        "BrokerID": "1",
        "DisplayName": "Broker ID 1"
    },
    {
        "BrokerID": "2",
        "DisplayName": "Broker ID 2"
    },
```

etc. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/442h4djr/9/).

Comment: Is there any way how to force Kendo using IDs as numbers? Because using numbers as strings means data type mess and WebAPI controller I'm using as data input (via AJAX) returns correct types. So ID in model is number and returned value (for other service method) must be number too.

Comment: Well, in this demo, they are using number as value, so there must be something different wrong? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-value

Comment: It may be that Kendo knows what to do with Kendo observables and doesn't adapt your virtual thing. I don't know Kendo. The value of a select is always supposed to be a string, as I recall.